# What is the correct way to access a model in an controller on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new on Laravel 4 and I am trying to understand it.

is searched on google and on stackoverflow. Maybe i am not searching for the right syntax but i hope someone can help me, with it.

In CodeIgniter i understand it (probably). There I use in an Controller:

```
function __construct()
{ $this->load->model('example_m'); }
```

But how about in Laravel 4?

I figured out the following:

i make a static function in de model so i can access it everywhere. Example:

```
class Example extends Eloquent // this is the model
{ 
   public static function TestExample(){
      // do some stuff here
   }
}
```

Or i could do it like this:

```
class ExampleController extends BaseController
{
   public $test = null;
   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->test = new Example();
   }
   public function index()
   {
      $this->test->TestExample();
   }
}
```

My question is: Is there an other way and/or what is the correct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://four.laravel.com/docs/ioc

```
App::bind('ExampleModelInterface', 'Example');

class ExampleController extends BaseController {
    public function __construct(ExampleModelInterface $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean simply accessing the method of a model?

Since they are static you use: Modell::method()

You might have to do a composer dump-autoload though so L4 autoloads it correctly.